# GitHub Actions. In which branch should the workflow files be located?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have 2 branches: **main (default)** and **dev**.

In the test branch I have the following workflow file:

```
on:
  push:    
    branches: [ test ]
```

...

There is no such file in the main branch.

When trying to push into the test branch, my workflow does not react in any way.

Where and why should this file be located?
What if the same file is located in several branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When trying to push into the test branch, my workflow does not react in any way.

The workflow file you mention in dev should be in the test branch first, in order for said workflow to be triggered.

See also "[How to run different Github Actions for the different git branches](https://ismailyenigul.medium.com/how-to-run-different-github-actions-for-the-different-git-branches-ede67b6083e3)" from [Ismail Yenigül](https://github.com/ismailyenigul):

> You can create different `.yml` files under the `repo/.github/workflows` directory for each different branch you want to enable GitHub actions.

The syntax would be (see "[Using activity types and filters with multiple events](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#using-filters)"):

```yaml
on:
  push:    
    branches: 
      - test
```

The "array `[ xx, yy ]`" syntax is more for event `types:` for instance, not for `branches:`.

Comment: I created a workflow in the test branch that listens to events for the test branch, and it doesn't work.

Comment: There was a typo in the question. I fixed it, in any case, if I don't have this file in one of the branches, nothing works.

Comment: @SantaMonica Maybe it is a syntax issue. Can you try the one illustrated in the [article I mentioned](https://ismailyenigul.medium.com/how-to-run-different-github-actions-for-the-different-git-branches-ede67b6083e3)?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I created a test project and everything works fine. I'll figure it out. @VonC

Comment: @SantaMonica Great, well done!